# Mounting volume while in Recovery Mode keeps rebooting

Tags: macos, recovery, mojave, apfs

My computer crashed while editing a video with Final Cut. I have been unable to boot up since then - the OS crashes immediately after typing my password at the login screen and reboots.

I’ve been going into Recovery Mode now, trying to perform any kind of repair. Unfortunately, whether I mount my APFS volume via Disk Utility or using the Terminal’s ‘diskutil APFS unlockVolume’, I can get it to mount successfully, but then my computer reboots immediately before I am able to perform First Aid or run a ‘fsck_apfs’ command.

I know the simple solution is to reformat and reinstall my OS. For obvious reasons, I’d like to repair things if at all possible before resorting to that.

Is there a different approach I can use to get my drive mounted and attempt a repair, without the machine restarting right away?

Comment: what does it do in safe mode ? do you have bootable USB disk

Comment: I do not have a bootable USB disk set up for my Mac. When trying to boot into safe mode, the system just boots up normally instead and takes me to the login screen, where I crash upon proceeding.

Comment: Interesting... that safe mode does not work. Sounds like your EFI partition is screwed up. I can not help you further with that tonight.

Comment: From what I understand, safe mode will not work because I use File Vault encryption on that drive